# How do I show only the WooCommerce SKU number?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sku

For example, my SKU number is "ZKY-KDN-KTP-167754"
I want to show only number "167754" and hide the letters. Without deleting.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to give the `class="sku_wrapper"`  an `visibility: hidden;`. 
And give the `class="sku"` wich is inside the **sku_wrapper** an `visibility: initial;`

Tested and works

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here:

1. Replace the single product template (woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php) from your theme, and where is the sku you can use a **REGEX to keep only numbers** like this:

   ```
   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

   <?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>

       $sku = $product->get_sku() ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
       $sku = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $sku);

       <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo $sku; ?></span></span>

   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

   <?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>
   ```
2. Use Javascript (non-recommended)